# Google Sheets - Multiple criteria match within an array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, string-matching

I am trying to find a way to return a match when looking at multiple criteria within an array formula.

[Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/152o6mAtDqJuAvCBanMNKhrwHuuiy-2noSxqp4fpswro/edit?usp=sharing)

I can return the correct matches using the Filter function (formula below); however, this is very slow when matching 10,000+ rows, so I need to find a single formula that achieves the same results but one that is much more efficient.

(Column G.) =FILTER($D$2:$D15,$A$2:$A15=$A2,$B$2:$B15=$B2,$C$2:$C15=$C2,$E$2:$E15="Brake Adaptor")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(A2:A),VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&"Brake Adaptor",{A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E,D2:D},2,),))
```

[image]